# Powershell - Adding milliseconds to timestamp

Tags: powershell, timestamp, milliseconds

I am trying to create a timestamp string in the format:

```
yyyymmddhhmmssfff
```

where `f` is milliseconds.

Example: `20171013180359235`

So far I have

```
[string]$Date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
```

With this I get only up to the seconds. I know if I add %l to the end I get a precision of 2 milliseconds, but I am one short. Is there any way to describe how precise I can choose the milliseconds. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the .tostring() method of the datetime object:

```
 (get-date).ToString('yymmddhhmmssfff')
```

171513121549340

Comment: You should capitalize the first set of double Ms, for month.
(get-date).ToString('yyMMddhhmmssfff')

Comment: @MeMyself  This has caused me some grief in the past!!

Answer (score 1):

I use this for some of my work (think, naming files): `Get-Date -Format 'DyyyyMMddThhmmsstt.fffffff'`. The capital D is for Date and the capital T for time. Perhaps this is helpful!

`D20171013T101807AM.8629943`

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. But your code amended to: `Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddhhmmssfff'` That gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The hour format specifier is case sensitive - lower case uses 12 hour clock and uppercase 24 hours. I suspect you would prefer 24 hour. So 'yyMMddHHmmssfff'