# powershell string to datetime with milliseconds conversion

Tags: powershell, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

In PowerShell, how can I convert string in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ms+tz format to datetime? To be able to calculate time difference between two datetimes in such format.

I played with

```
 [System.DateTime]::ParseExact($time_start,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:SS.ms',$null)
```

but without sucess. Just getting error:

```
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String '"2023-03-17T18:37:19.717+02:00"' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

finally I wanted to get date1 - date2 result in milliseconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `Get-Date '2023-03-17T18:37:19.717+02:00'` ?

Comment: The answer to your specific question is a duplicate with [Powershell - Adding milliseconds to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46734884/1701026) but if you want to "*calculate time difference*", you should first subtract the dates whch results in a [timespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan) and than [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[datetime]'2023-03-17T13:23:01.002'` Oh I think you need to delete the extra double-quotes.

```
$time_start = '"2023-03-17T18:37:19.717+02:00"'
[datetime]($time_start -replace '"')

Friday, March 17, 2023 12:37:19 PM
```

Comment: Thank you, that works for me. After deleting extra quotes (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $time_start –End $time_end).TotalMilliseconds works perfectly.